# Vxworks network stack, job queue, and memory pool

Tags: networking, ip, vxworks

I'm looking into clearing state on the Vxworks6.9 network stack for security purposes. I'm working with a vxsim target and the sample downloadable kernel module ball project from the workbench guide, and am trying to clear any parts of the stack possible by either destroying tNet0 and re-initializing it, calling free() on tNet0's jobQueue/removing jobs, or freeing the memory_pool/memory_slab/netJobPool structures.

I tried first with deleting tNet0 (formerly tNetTask) by calling taskDelete() then netLibInitialize() (I believe shouldn't be called besides at startup) but then I can't ping the IP address so that seems to silently fail.

Calling free(&netDaemons[0].jobQueue) doesn't seem to stop the ongoing TCP connection I'm using for testing so the net stack is untouched. Really I think this is because that variable isn't accessible in the correct context (during the first call of daemon initialization  on startup).

Finally, I'm exploring freeing the memory pool used by tNet0 or its job queue but can't seem to access the memoryPoolDestroy(poolID) or other needed functions because the relevant context of  vxworks-6.9/target/h/wrn/coreip/jobQueueLib.h  isn't reachable (seg violation).

Is there a suggested way to clear state for the net stack?